# How do I indicate which language to render in the browser using l20n.js?

Tags: javascript, html, json, localization, l20n

I am using l20n.js to add localization to an Angular.js app. Here's my project structure:

## /index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js">    </script>
  <script src="trackingController.js"></script>
  <script src="l20n.js"></script>
  <link rel="localization" href="locales/manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
  <h2 data-l10n-id="name"></h2>
  <p data-l10n-id="instructions"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

## /locales/manifest.json

```
{
  "locales": [ "en-US", "fr-FR"],
  "default_locale": "en-US",
  "resources": [
    "{{locale}}/strings.l20n",
  ]
}
```

## /locales/en-US/strings.l20n

```
<name "Search by name - EN">
<instructions "Enter one or more names - EN">
```

## /locales/fr-FR/strings.l20n

```
<name "Search by name - FR">
<instructions "Enter one or more names - FR">
```

How can I swap out English (i.e. the `/locales/en/strings.l20n` file) for French? It renders en-US despite indicating `lang="fr-FR"` in `index.html`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, L20n uses the browser's language settings to determine which locale to show to the user.  I'm guessing that your browser has 'en' or 'en-US' in the language setting somewhere.  You can preview your setting by opening the developer console (Ctrl+Shift+K in Firefox, Ctrl+Shift+J in Chrome) and typing `navigator.language` or (in newer versions of Firefox) `navigator.languages`.

In Firefox, you can change your language preferences by going into `about:preferences#content`, and clicking 'Choose' under 'Languages'.  In Chrome, there is a similar panel in the Settings, but it actually doesn't modify the `navigator.language` property, which is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=101138).  You'll need to download and install a French version of Chrome if you want to test this way.

An alternative is to use the L20n API and explicitly change the language with:

```
document.l10n.requestLanguages(['fr']);
```

This is useful if you want to provide a piece of UI to let your users change the language of the app.  For instance, you could have a drop-down menu with all languages that you support, which calls `document.l10n.requestLanguages` when a new option is selected.

Comment: I didn't realize it was a browser setting, I thought I had to specify the language setting myself. Thanks!

Comment: requestLocales method has disappeared from l10n object in at least v3.0.6. How can one change locale explicitly in latest versions?

Comment: I'm working on a patch which will bring it back: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1207120. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: @Antoine: I published v3.1.0 last night which re-introduced `document.l10n.requestLanguages()`.

Comment: Thanks, @Supersharp, for pointing this out. In version 3.x of L20n.js, the method is called `requestLanguages` and takes a single argument: an array of language codes in order of user's preference. It replaces the obsolete `requestLocales` method.  I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Obviously, as date of 03-15-16, `requestLanguages()` method is replaced **AGAIN** by `requestLocales()`. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/L20n/L20n_Javascript_API). I am really not fond of the way they change API and tell you it's not backward-compatible.  A good advice is to put a link of API on the official l20n page

Answer (score 3):

Use the L20n JavaScript API [requestLocales()](https://github.com/l20n/l20n.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#ctxrequestlocalesrequestedlocales-string)

## /index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js">    </script>
  <script src="trackingController.js"></script>
  <script src="l20n.js"></script>
  <link rel="localization" href="locales/manifest.json">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#langSwitch-en').click(function() {
      document.l10n.requestLocales('en-US');
    });
    $('#langSwitch-fr').click(function() {
      document.l10n.requestLocales('fr-FR');
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- fix the correct language code [-de] for [-fr] -->
  <a id="langSwitch-en" href="#">en</a> / <a id="langSwitch-fr" href="#">fr</a>
  <h2 data-l10n-id="name"></h2>
  <p data-l10n-id="instructions"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. A small mistake of jquery functions. Either put that script on document ready or place the script at the end of body. Currently its not working as it is.